# Getting value of boundfield in gridview from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datagrid in asp.net, with a boundfield. On the RowCommand event, I want to get the value of this boundfield. The boundfield, in the columns tag, loooks as below:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LoginID" HeaderText="LoginID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LoginID" />
```

What would the accompanying C# be?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you mean GridView not DataGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Row_Command Event you can retrieve the index of the clicked Row in this way :

```
 void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {

    //Check if it's the right CommandName... 
    if(e.CommandName=="Add")
    {
      //Get the Row Index
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

      // Retrieve the row
      GridViewRow row = ContactsGridView.Rows[index];

      // Here you can access the Row Cells 
      row.Cells[1].Text

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void gv_research_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                if (e.CommandName == "editResearch")
                {

                    txt_researchName.Text = gv_research.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text.TrimEnd();

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string message = ee.Message;

            }
        }
```

---

**.aspx:**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Edit" runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>' CommandName="editResearch" />
```